# What's the best web based tool to manage postfix?

Tags: postfix

There are a ton of programs listed here under "Run/Configuration/Queue/User management"

http://www.postfix.org/addon.html

Just curious if anyone has used these and what is recommended. Basically I want to see what is going on with my queue, view/manage different user account, and any problems/bottlenecks. pfqueue is decent but is command line based.  Basically I'm looking for the phpMyAdmin of postfix.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://sourceforge.net/projects/postfixadmin/

However it just manages domain, domain admins, accounts, etc. Not the queues or the actual config of the server.

Comment: +1 for postfixadmin. But, the value of being able to troubleshoot and investigate with the inbuilt tools is priceless

Comment: Cool, looks awesome.  If it had some performance metrics would be perfect!

Answer (score 4):

This might be a bit heavier than what you're looking for, but [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)'s Postfix module (which is a standard module) will provide you with the tools you want - including the ability to look at the queue, look inside mailboxes, etc.

Comment: Wow that has a TON of features, one small part of which is Postfix.  Not sure it's perfect, but thanks for the submission!

Comment: We've used it for some time.  Just don't use it to manipulate the aliases file (there's an occasional bug) but otherwise, it's fine.